# Display locally available JPEG-encoded blog on the HTML5 canvas - browser tries to connect to the webserver

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, blob

I have implemented a code to capture video stream from user's camera, and encode it to JPEG, which is then uploaded to the server via websocket. It **works** beautifully, 10 fps is no problem. The relevant code snippets:

```
// Get webcam access
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {       
    navigator.getUserMedia({video: true}, handleVideo, videoError);
} 
function handleVideo(stream) {
    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
}
```

...

```
// Elements for taking the snapshot
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var video = document.getElementById('videoElement');
```

...

```
// Trigger Frame Capture
setInterval(CaptureTimer, 100);
function CaptureTimer() {
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
            ws.send(blob);
        }, "image/jpeg", 0.5);  
}
```

(don't try to run the code as is, non-essential parts are not shown. It works by painting the video source in a canvas and then packing it in a JPEG encoded blob, which is then sent by a websocket). No errors in Javascript console, and valid images are recorded on a server.

However, I also need to be able to **get processed images from the server**, and display them in a canvas. So to test things locally, I added few lines  to draw the binary blob back to other canvas (before going back and forth through websocket connection):

```
// Elements for drawing the blobbed image
var rcanvas = document.getElementById('rcanvas');
var rcontext = rcanvas.getContext('2d');
var rimage = new window.Image();
// Connect rimage to rcontext
rimage.onload = function(){
  rcontext.drawImage(rimage,0,0); 
};
```

...

```
// Trigger Frame Capture
setInterval(CaptureTimer, 100);
function CaptureTimer() {
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
        ws.send(blob);
        rimage.src = blob;
        };
      }, "image/jpeg", 0.5);
```

So, basically I try to load **my locally generated** blob into the other canvas. It does not work. In the javascript console I get 404 error, since the browser wants to GET:

```
http://myserver.com/wwwpath/mydir/[object Blob]
```

Of course, this results in 404 Not Found, since the blob exists only locally as variable in Javascript. Note that also tried with using blob.slice(0) to obtain copy of the "blob" object, same error.

What I am doing wrong? I was  sure that capturing and uploading video was the hardest part... not the simple action of displaying the JPEG blob in Canvas.

Testing in the latest Firefox ESR 52.4.1 (64-bit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a [`Blob URL`](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#DefinitionOfScheme) as `img` `src` instead of a `Blob`

```
let blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
rimage.src = blobURL;
```

You can revoke the `Blob URL` following procedure,  when the reference to the `Blob URL` is no longer needed

```
URL.revokeObjectURL(blobURL);
```

Comment: You, Sir, rock. The fastest answer ever and I have to wait 6 minutes to accept it.